# not matching when inside mysql case statement is not showing in result

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, case

I have an mysql statement as below

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN HOUR(created_at) BETWEEN 0 AND 11 THEN 'Morning'
       WHEN HOUR(created_at) BETWEEN 12 AND 15 THEN 'Afternoon'
       WHEN HOUR(created_at) BETWEEN 16 AND 18 THEN 'Evening'
       WHEN HOUR(created_at) BETWEEN 19 AND 24 THEN 'Night'
   END AS session,
   SUM(total) AS `total` FROM `orders`  WHERE (purchase_date between '2014-05-01' and '2014-05-30')
   GROUP BY CASE
         WHEN HOUR(created_at) BETWEEN 0 AND 11 THEN 1
         WHEN HOUR(created_at) BETWEEN 12 AND 16 THEN 2
         WHEN HOUR(created_at) BETWEEN 17 AND 18 THEN 3
         WHEN HOUR(created_at) BETWEEN 19 AND 24 THEN 4
     END;
```

I am getting an output like this

```
+------------+------------+
| session    | total      |
+------------+------------+
| Morning    |   47083.21 |
| Afternoon  | 1124804.51 |
| Evening    |  165643.34 |
| Night      | 1690492.01 |
+------------+------------+
```

But when there are no entries for morning then the output is missing the Morning row in results but I want an row with morning but total as 0.
please help me how to achieve the same

```
Expected output

+------------+------------+
| session    | total      |
+------------+------------+
| Morning    |          0 |
| Afternoon  |   14804.51 |
| Evening    |   16643.34 |
| Night      |   19492.01 |
+------------+------------+
```

actual output is without morning row

```
Actual output

+------------+------------+
| session    | total      |
+------------+------------+
| Afternoon  | 1124804.51 |
| Evening    |  165643.34 |
| Night      | 1690492.01 |
+------------+------------+
```

I would greatly appreciate if Any kind of help or hint is given to solve this problem

Comment: you need only from that query itself?

Comment: not necessarily the same query but if there is any other alternate query is also fine

Comment: i don't want to go with the alternate query with that query only i want to use the o/p with condition...if total=0 skip that record is it fine?

Comment: if total is zero then that result shld be reflected

Answer (score 0):

Add  `create table cal (hours int not null)`. Fill it with 0 to 23 (there is no 24 hour?).    Then do

```
SELECT CASE
   WHEN cal.hours BETWEEN 0 AND 11 THEN 'Morning'
   WHEN cal.hours BETWEEN 12 AND 15 THEN 'Afternoon'
   WHEN cal.hours BETWEEN 16 AND 18 THEN 'Evening'
   WHEN cal.hours BETWEEN 19 AND 24 THEN 'Night'
END AS session
,sum(coalesce(total, 0)) from
(select  created_at, total from orders 
 where purchase_date between '2014-05-01' and '2014-05-30') T1
 right outer  join cal on (cal.hours = hour(T1.created_at))
group by CASE
   WHEN cal.hours BETWEEN 0 AND 11 THEN 'Morning'
   WHEN cal.hours BETWEEN 12 AND 15 THEN 'Afternoon'
   WHEN cal.hours BETWEEN 16 AND 18 THEN 'Evening'
   WHEN cal.hours BETWEEN 19 AND 24 THEN 'Night' END;
```

Comment: Hi @dan b...This query doesn't work as expected. it is still missing the morning row as there are no data for morning in orders table. even after this left outer join with cal table.

Comment: @Peru Can you try it now

Comment: @Peru   Fixed again.  Changed left outer join to right outer join and use coalesce

Comment: ........still the same result. Morning row is still missing in the ouput. not able to figure out why

Comment: in fact left outer join, right outer join, inner join and plain join also doesn't work

Comment: Take a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c79cae/1/0. There you will see a similar example that works.  If yours is still not working post to sql fiddle.

Comment: Hi @dan b Thanks a lot for putting so much effort, the sqlfiddle you have given works but the same thing is not working the moment you add where statement.

just add this dummy where clause 
    where `orders`.`total` > 1
and you can see that the row with zeros doesn't come in result.

The problem is after adding where clause. 
I don't understand why where clause is a problem here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68554/discussion-between-peru-and-dan-b).